# Processing video file after uploading in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, video-processing, azure-blob-storage

does anyone have any sample code/tutorials on processing a video file uploaded to Azure (.mov, .3gp, .avi) and **converting it to flash and also creating a thumbnail file** after the video has been uploaded as a blob to Azure? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wade Wegner had a nice blog bosting on this very topic.

http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/using-expression-encoder-4-in-a-windows-azure-worker-role/